# Group many rows with string in google query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, flatten, google-query-language

I have a problem with my google query. I need to group several lines and some are repeated.

At row F2 I have the
`=ArrayFormula(query(TO_TEXT({A3:A\SE(G1:AK1>=B3:B;SE(G1:AK1<=B3:B+C3:C-1;D3:D;"*");"*")});"SELECT * where Col1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Col1"))`
the result is:

[image]

I want the result to be the same as the image below:

[image]

Link to sheets: [enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s7vd99qWOVNs6eZzKpUQnykv4tjwH4l6lkTTgBQ8Y8E/edit#gid=1782117491)

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please share your sheet publicly with sample input and expected output.

Comment: I messaged you via the "Access Denied" page that returns with your link. As Carlos mentioned, please change the link permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" so that the volunteer contributors here can actually access the sheet, test formulas with your data and leave any working formulas in-sheet for you (as well as posting them here, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(COLUMN(1:1)<=C3:C; A3:A&"×"&TEXT(B3:B+COLUMN(1:1)-1; 
 "yyyymmdd\¤d")&"×"&D3:D; )); "×"); 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col2")); "^(.*¤)";))
```

[image]

---

to force dates in row 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(COLUMN(1:1)<=C3:C; A3:A&"×"&B3:B+COLUMN(1:1)-1&"×"&D3:D; )); "×"); 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "limit 0 label Col1'xx'"; 1)*1);
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(COLUMN(1:1)<=C3:C; A3:A&"×"&B3:B+COLUMN(1:1)-1&"×"&D3:D; )); "×"); 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "offset 1"; 0)})
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR({IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF((MONTH(B3:B)=MONTH(D1))*(COLUMN(1:1)<=C3:C); A3:A&"×"&B3:B+COLUMN(1:1)-1&"×"&D3:D; )); "×"); 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "limit 0 label Col1'xx'"; 1)*1);
 QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF((MONTH(B3:B)=MONTH(D1))*(COLUMN(1:1)<=C3:C); A3:A&"×"&B3:B+COLUMN(1:1)-1&"×"&D3:D; )); "×"); 
 "select Col1,max(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); "offset 1"; 0)}; "no data"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help"). The following single array formula can be found in cell F1:

`=ArrayFormula({""\TEXT(SEQUENCE(1;DAY(EOMONTH(B3;0));EOMONTH(B3;-1)+1);"d");SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A;A3:A<>"")))\IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A;A3:A<>"")))&SEQUENCE(1;DAY(EOMONTH(B3;0));EOMONTH(B3;-1)+1));SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(FILTER(A3:A&(B3:B+IF(SEQUENCE(1;14;0)<C3:C;SEQUENCE(1;14;0)))&"~"&D3:D;A3:A<>"")));"~");2;FALSE))})`

The formula produces all left-side labels, all top headers and all grid results.

The formula assumes that all dates in the sheet's Col D will be in the same month/year (based on your posted images running 1-31).

It also assumes that no event will span more than a 14-day period. If any event *will* exceed 14 days, you'll need to change the `14` in the formula to the maximum possible number of days any one event may span per ID.

It is further assumed that no two "Justificatory" labels will overlap on the same dates per ID.

This formula goes beyond the norm in complexity for this free volunteer-run forum. I trust you'll understand that I don't have the time, in addition to having developed the formula, to also explain it. I encourage you (or others who might be interested) to dig into it, take it apart, and explore independently how it all works.